# File not found error on creating a new file and writing in it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a new file and write on it . but when I am doing something like this I am getting file not found error. seems I am missing something which I can't figure out .

```
data = {
    "table_name": "name",
}
file_path = '/tmp/myfile.json'
with open(file_path + '.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

**[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/myfile.json'**

Comment: The could shown will **not** produce that exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to run this on Windows by any chance? Or a *nix system where you don't have access to `/tmp`?

For me, this script runs fine on a Ubuntu and MacOS (although the created file is `/tmp/myfile.json.json` instead of `/tmp/myfile.json` because of the `+ '.json'` in your script), but not on Windows.

Comment: I am using unix and I have access to /tmp

Comment: hiiii , yes this was issue :(  file was being created as json.json  thanks mate for help . dumb mistake by me

Comment: Glad I helped... but that's weird. I would expect it to just create a `*.json.json` file, not throw an exception.

Comment: The code shown by @shahzor will **not** generate the exception shown. There's something else going on. My guess is that /tmp/myfile.json.json is being created. Subsequently (in code not shown) there is an attempt to open /tmp/myfile.json which then fails

Answer (score 0):

well python tries to find the file in the cuurent working directory, check if the `cwd` is what you think it is

```py
import pathlib

print(pathlib.Path().absolute())
```

u can do this to check the `cwd`

Comment: thanks for answer . yes on first it's not present . but I want to create one and then update data in it. am I doing right ?

Comment: well, not really, u didn't write anything to make a `dir` and add a `.json` file to it

Comment: u can use modules like `shutil` and `os` to do that, i would recommend taking a look at their docs

Comment: and sry, i didnt read ur question properly at first 

Comment: dir  exists .. but not file

Comment: I don't see why you suggest this: OP use an absolute path `/tmp...`, so why should the CWD matter?